# in my external monitor with max resolution everything looks big and ugly, how can I fix this?

Tags: kde, display, monitors, resolution, display-settings

when I connect my external monitor everything looks so big, the code font in my editor inside my laptop has a small and pretty font but when I move to the external monitor is like a zoom instead of increase the desktop space

I was doubtful if it should be like that because the monitor is new but I test it with a macbook and it works really well, the monitor keeps the dimensions of the elements..it doesn't seem like it's zooming which it does on linux

I'm using manjaro KDE, my laptop monitor and the monitor has the same resolution (1920x1080)

is possible fix this? please let me know if you need more information

[image: kde config]

thank you so much

Comment: You probably have scaling on. 1. Make sure the resolution of the external monitor is set correctly (in your KDE display settings) 2. make sure your Hi-DPI settings do not apply.